# Installing ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, installation

I am installing ArcGIS Pro onto my computer.  This is a work computer with multiple users but I have the permissions necessary to install where I want.

I am trying to follow these instructions: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/install-and-sign-in-to-arcgis-pro.htm to install specifically to the file path `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro`.  However this is failing.

My ArcGIS Desktop which enables my Pro license is a 32 bit and installed in `C:\Program Files(86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6`.  So there was NO `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro` path.  I created and empty folder path --> `...\ArcGIS\Pro` and tried installing there, to no avail.

Does it matter where I install it?  The recommended path by the installer executable is `C:\Users\<myusername>\Documents\ArcGIS Pro 2.5`.  I would prefer to install for all users.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Keep in mid that Esri uses a two-phase install.  The first execution extracts the installer, then it executes that installer.  So the *first* time you're prompted for a location, use a place you're likely to find to delete from (e.g., Desktop\Temp) then the real installer will offer the one user/all users choice, with C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro as the default (FWIW: I ***never*** install user applications in C:)

Comment: @Vince This should probably be an answer

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the detailed response.  As I recall I was only prompted for an install location once.  This directory became the parent directory for both the Windows Installer and the Cabinet File (software itself I imagine?). What do you mean by "user application"?  Just an update I did take the path of least resistance and use the default offered by the installer - in Documents.

Comment: @NW_Photo_Laureate Usually when you run the downloaded file it will ask where to unpack it to, and after some time it will complete the unpack and ask you if you want to run the installer.  At this point it should give the regular installation type dialogs which would include specifying where to install it.  By default it will install to `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro`, but it will offer to unpack it somewhere else _first_

Comment: Midavalo - you and @Vince certainly nailed it.  Simple process I just hadn't picked up on in the past when installing Arc software (and undoubtedly countless other software).  I choose the location to unzip the installers too (temp) and THEN the install path which was my confusion.